# twitter like open source software for .Net platform?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, twitter

I am wondering whether there is twitter like open source platform written in .Net (C#, ASP.Net, SQL Server, etc)? I want to integrate twitter like feature into my own web application, but not want to use public twitter service.

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe http://sourceforge.net/projects/shoutout-twitte/.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean an open source API wrapper? If so, then maybe Flurr? http://flurr.codeplex.com/